# mdicontainer overlap the childcontrol

Tags: c#-4.0

In my application I have a main page with a menustrip to navigate to other forms Since i want it to be opened always I set it as a MDICONTAINER .now I need to open a form on menustripclick event as child  i set the form like this

```
 public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
            loginmain();


            intialsetupform();

        }

        private void companyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Master.CompanyMasterForm cmpnymasterform = new Master.CompanyMasterForm();
          cmpnymasterform.MdiParent= this ;

            cmpnymasterform.Show();
        }}
```

All was Ok and I got the childwindows work correctly
 but Now i need to add two panels in the mainform << one for showing status meddages and other for showing some other controls

I had added the panel  and anchored them  and the issue is that now when the child window  opens all the panels and controls of the parentform(mainform) comes above the childwindow controls  which make it unreadable  Please provide any ideas  to overcome this

Comment: You have to *dock* those panels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had set the location of all the pannels using Anchor properties of the control  now the controls know there location
and set the message box to bottom using dock property